# c# Conditional Regular Expression String Match

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use c# Regular Expression to match a particular string of characters but I can not figure out how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

The string that I am trying to match is as follows, where A is an uppercase alpha character, X is an upper case alpha-numeric character and # is 0, 1 or 2.

`AA-#-XX-X-XXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX`

So any of the following would match the string above.

`XY-1`

`MM-0-AB`

`MM-0-AB-1-ABC-1234567`

`VV-2-XX-7-CCC-ABCDEFG-12345678`

Any any of the following would NOT match.

`QQ-7-AA` (Only 0, 1, 2 are allowed at the second level.)

`QQ-2-XX-7-CC` (Partial characters for that level.)

`QQ-2-XX-7-CCC-ABCDEFG-` (Can not end in a dash.)

`QQ-2-XX-7-CCC-ABCDEFG-123456` (Partial characters for that level.)

So far (not that far really) I have as the pattern to match `@"^[A-Z]{2}"`, but I am unsure how to match conditionally (I'm not even sure if conditionally is the proper term to use) the rest of the string, but only if it is there. Do I need to write 7 different statements for this? Seems unreasonable, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). You need the following elements:

- uppercase alpha character: `[A-Z]`
- upper case alpha-numeric character: `[A-Z0-9]`
- 0, 1 or 2: `[0-2]`
- dash: `-`
- match *x* exactly *n* times: `x{n}`
- match *x* zero or one time: `x?`
- define a subexpression: `(`...`)`

*Examples:*

- two uppercase alpha characters: `[A-Z]{2}`
- two uppercase alpha characters, followed by a dash: `[A-Z]{2}-`
- two uppercase alpha characters, followed by a dash, followed by 0, 1 or 2: `[A-Z]{2}-[0-2]`
- two uppercase alpha characters, followed by a dash, followed by 0, 1 or 2, but with the subexpression consisting of the dash and 0, 1 or 2 occurring zero or one time:
  `[A-Z]{2}(-[0-2])?`
- and so on...

*Resulting expression:*

```
^[A-Z]{2}(-[0-2](-[A-Z0-9]{2}(-[A-Z0-9](-[A-Z0-9]{3}(-[A-Z0-9]{7}(-[A-Z0-9]{8})?)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Comment: I was so close myself, but you beat me to it. Good and well explained answer! +1

Comment: I too was too slow. I thought there was a way to shorten the A-Z0-9 (like using "\d" for the 0-9), but I can't find it. Closest I got was "\w", but that includes too many characters.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer! I now understand the nesting of Regular Expressions!